# MVC ViewModel with editable and readonly data best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm wondering what is the best practice for dealing with editable/read only field in the same viewModel.
I'm facing this problem for a bigger ViewModel but let's assume I have a very simple ViewModel:

```
public class BaseListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheckedForAction { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

My PartialView:

```
@model Wims.Website.ViewModels.Shared.BaseModelListViewModel
@using Wims.Website.Classes.Helpers.ExtentionMethods
<div class="dataDetail">
        <div>
            <div class="float-left">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsCheckedForAction)
            </div>

            <div class="float-left">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsCheckedForAction, Model.DisplayName)


                @Html.GenerateSecureDataControls(w => w.Id)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Obviously, when i Post my data, DisplayName will not be filled.
Let's assume some validation fails, and I just return the data i recieved the DisplayName would be missing.

```
    [HttpPost]

public ActionResult Edit(BaseListViewModel stuff)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
        return View("Index");
    }
    return View(stuff);
}
```

I know there is several way to fix this:

1) add

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DisplayName)
```

in the view, which is ok if it's just 1 field, but, what happens if i do have 10 display only field?

2) requery data if (!Model.isValid) in [HttpPost].

3) I guess I could cache it in TempData ?

What is the best way to go for this?
Thanks!

**Edit: I am trying to avoid having to requery the data if validation fails**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. It is more DRY as you only build ViewModel in the GET action. If validation fails then redirect to GET and get the model state out of tempdata.

The attributes on from this article, http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/06/persisting-model-state-when-using-prg.html, or from MVC Contrib https://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/blob/master/src/MVCContrib/Filters/ModelStateToTempDataAttribute.cs,  make it easy to pass the Modelstate between the POST and the GET

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, I don't understand how those post would help me keep my ViewModel Readyonly data filled? I understand i can keep the modelState error to send them to another action. My question was more about keeping the unposted data filled in my ViewModel?

Comment: Why? Create the ViewModel once in the GET action. Put the Restore from [RestoreModelStateFromTempData] attribute on theGET. Put[SetTempDataModelState] on the POST. Then if ModelState validation fails redirect back to the GET. It will make a new ViewModel nd then merge in the submitted data and validation errors

Comment: Hi again, thanks for not giving up on me :) I think I understand what you are saying but what I am trying to avoid is go back to database (and yes, i didn't mention that) again in the second GET. What I could do, and maybe it's what suggesting (if it is sorry for being slow :) ) is do what you just wrote, and add the complete ViewModel in TempData after the first Get, and in the PRG pattern grab it from TempData? Thanks again

Comment: If you want to avoid trip to db again then yes need to put it to tempdata.  Should update question to reflect db requirement. Basically similar idea but merge in the display only fields. Must be an expensive database call! Not better to look at caching the db query results?

Comment: I tried just getting the data from the TempData without filtering anything, and on a simple test it worked, Readonly data are back and editable are set to edited value. It's not such a expensive call at all (several smalls ones), but I believe it's better to avoid if not really needed for optimisation sake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it works. I tend to avoid micro optimization unless it's needed.  Id tend to look at general caching etc. But maybe it's important for your business case. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The POST action should perform the same initialisation of the viewmodel as the GET action. You could move the initialisation code into a common private function in the controller. The reason for this is if validation fails because of some concurrent change to the same data, the validation errors would be displayed to the user along with the new data. You could use the PRG pattern as well if the views allow for it.